# SQL - Select * From Table Order By

Tags: sql

i have a table with values and what i try to is to select all but show in a different order .

i don´t want to add another column to define the display order,

how can i do that..

i have read about using case.

but i have no success, hope that someone can help with this.

here is my trying code:

My table looks like this:

```
 1 -- a
 2 -- b
 3 -- bgin
 4 -- mid 
 5 -- c
 6 -- d
```

and i my result i like to have are this:

```
 1 -- bgin
 2 -- a
 3 -- b
 4 -- c 
 5 -- d
 6 -- mid


Select Name From tbl
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN Name = 'Bgin' THEN 0 END, Name,
CASE WHEN Name= 'Mid' THEN 5 END, Name
```

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do? Why should bgin appear at the top instead of the bottom or any other place? Are there any criteria that define this order?

Comment: THat's not going to work.  Maybe you could use a case statement to derive a calculation you could sort by?  Not to mention, what's the logic driving this sort order?

Comment: @Andrew: you very much can use a case statement in ORDER BY, though the OP has not done it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select Name From tbl
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN Name = 'Bgin' THEN 0
     WHEN Name = 'Mid' THEN 5
     WHEN Name <> 'Mid' AND Name <> 'Bgin' THEN 1 END, Name
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f18fa/4)</kbd>